# processing large text in C#

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox, text-processing

I receive 15.000(can be more) lines from RichTextBox, I need to add some value to each line. 
What's the best way to do this, so that the program does not lock up?

Currently, I'm processing the lines in a loop which is running as a thread:

```
 public void Process()
        {

               string[] lines;
                string line;
                string foo = " baa";
                if (richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
                {

                    lines = (string[])Invoke((ReadLines)delegate
                    {
                        return /* read .Lines[] from richTextBox1 */
                    });
                    int max = lines.Length;

                    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
                    {
                        line = lines[i];
                        if (..)
                        {
                            lines[i] += "foo";
                        }
                    }

                    Invoke((Update)delegate
                    {
                        /* set new lines to RichTextBox1 */ 
                    });

              } 
       }
```

and Then:

```
Thread th1 = new Thread(Process);
 th1.Start();
```

but it still locks up. What's the best way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the nature of the beast unfortunately - rich text box control wasn't meant to hold that many lines, the assignment will lock up the UI. I would think "redesign" instead of "workaround"

Comment: Yeah. Either preprosess beorfore adding, but at the end - the text bos is just not made for that, get a commercial / proofessional editor component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry to say, but your best bet is NOT to use a text box but get an editor component (SyntaxEdit for example) that is designed for partial updates and handling large amounts of text. The UI does not lock up due to your processing but bevccause the text box just is inevfficient with large texts and the text box blocks the UI thread while it updates. It is not going to work without rewriting it. You are 14.900 lines larger than the spec for it, so to say. Every time you update the text in the box, it starts a really slow redrawing cycle. One that you can not interrupt, so all threading wont help - because the UI is unresponsibve until this update cycle is ended.

There are other components for "real text editors" that also are prepared to handle much larger text.

Comment: have not there another solution using RichTextBox? it is because I need highlight it some text..

Comment: Check SyntaxEdit - commercial, costs money, an editor component for progrmmers (highlighting etc.) and ble to handle LARGE files.

Answer (score 1):

Try a [BackgroundWorker control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403.aspx).

Comment: -1. VERY unlikely to handle the problem given the update already happens likely in a separate thread (ascan be seen on the invoke). Background worker wont handle the extreme long update time it takes the textbox. The UI will still lock up during this time.

Answer (score -1):

Running in a `BackgroundWorker` with some indication of progress may be your best bet (if you must use the RichTextBox). Even one of those spinning AJAX images may be enough.

Comment: -1. Indication is nice, but it wont handle theproblem (UI locks up) that the poster SPECIFICALLY asked for.